# Which postgres system table stores a map of PIDs to session authorizations?

Tags: postgresql, session, pid, system-tables

I want to look further into the PIDs listed in `pg_stat_activity` to know what their last succesful call to `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` set their session authorization to.  Which table or view do I need on PostgreSQL 9.0?

Comment: I don't think there's any such record exposed; you can see the login session user in `pg_stat_activity` but not any session- or role- assumed user. At least on my 9.3. Perhaps this is worth raising on the pgsql-general mailing list? It might be good information to expose via p.s.a if we can do it without an undue performance impact.

Comment: ... so you will have to use the logs, logging the session ID and the pid. Not fun.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Oh, for some reason I had assumed that every last variable was somehow stored in a table.  :)  Well, yours is a valid answer if you want to add it as such...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't expose that information, at least in 9.4 or any prior version.

The user id in `pg_stat_activity` is the login user; it's the user that `RESET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` goes back to. It won't change when you `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` or `SET ROLE`.

Information about the current effective session authorization and current role are internal to the backend. You can access them locally to the backend with `SELECT current_user, current_role`, etc, but there's no inter-process way to get at them.

It might be nice to have that, if it could be added without making it more expensive to maintain `pg_stat_activity` or to query it. You'd need to get into PostgreSQL's guts and develop a patch to expose the information, though.

Surprisingly, [`log_line_prefix`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX) doesn't seem to include format symbols to show the effective role and effective session user. Given the use of session authorization by PgBouncer that's sufficiently odd that I feel like I must have missed something.

In any case, the only way I see to do this is to dig through the logs, logging pid and session ID then associating successful `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` calls with subsequent statements.